# SQL Slower for 2013 dates?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a few queries that provide me with a set of data. Now Prior to 2013 they run as fast as expected based on the amount of data that they query. But now its just as slow as hell.
Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT TOP 25 UserDetail,
                      isnull(ROUND(SUM(Cost), 2), 0) AS MixedCost
        FROM   PCounter.dbo.PrintJobsWithUserDetail
        WHERE  Month(PrintDate) = 1
               AND Year(PrintDate) = 2013
        GROUP  BY UserDetail
        ORDER  BY MixedCost DESC) AS A
ORDER  BY A.MixedCost ASC
```

Now this query executes in 2 seconds for Month = 1 Year = 2012
and it takes ¬3mins for 2013.

Am i going mad?
P.S The amount of data is more or less the same for each month

Comment: Conspiracy to make you purchase SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Depending on your indexes, it may be much quicker to change your WHERE to `WHERE PrintDate BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-31'`

Comment: no it does not. All the queries that involve any past date are of the same speed but when it runs for 2013 it is slow that should not be the same @TimSchmelter

Comment: Is the Year(2013) a parameter or a literal in your tests? First suspect is parameter sniffing if your data sizes are alike for each year.

Comment: It might be that your previous querys were in cache. And by the way, if you have an index on `PrintDate` (it seems that you should), the way you are doing your filter makes it impossible to use that index

Comment: @MarkD Year(PrintDate) = -value selected from dropdown-

Comment: Does it hit the DB as SQL code or as an SP call?

Comment: @MarkD the thing is i keep running the same stored procedure for 2013 and it wont speed up. If it was a problem of sniffing wouldnt that increase the speed?

Comment: normaly as SQL Code but atm i am testing this from SQL Studio

Comment: What you get when try `Where PrintDate >= '20130101' ?

Comment: equally slow @HamletHakobyan

Comment: Then you must show as actual execution plans for both querys, i.e. for years 2012 and 2013.

Comment: +1 to @cjk - current predicats isn't SARGable

Comment: @cjk - please don't use `BETWEEN`, even when dealing with dates (and [especially on SQL Server](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)) - and since we don't know that the column is **actually** a `Date` type.

Comment: Its a datetime type but why now?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse 1. It has to be a date type for YEAR(blah) to work on it. 2. AB's article is a matter of prudence, not functionality

Comment: @MarkD - given the documentation, `YEAR(...)` (and related) work on anything date-based, including `datetime` (which the OP has listed as being the case).  The concept behind cjk's answer (to use a SARGable form) is good, but using `BETWEEN` will now for sure not work.  Which is why I tend to pass the article around; just in case it's for sure relevant.

Comment: @clockwork-muse good article, very interesting. Will make me rethink my betweens...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - haha, been bitten already today by `BETWEEN` :)

Answer (score 1):

If Parameter Sniffing is the culprit...
Inside your SP, try the following;

```
ALTER PROC MyProc
@YearParm INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DummyParm INT
    SET @DummyParm = @YearParm

    [SP LOGIC]  

END
```

Also, I agree 100% with @CJK.
The method of date filtering will negate indexes as it is not `SARG`able

Comment: i dont get how this helps the query??

Comment: You can either try it or read this whole article and then go try it: http://www.practicalsqldba.com/2012/06/sql-server-parameter-sniffing.html Lets first find out if this is the problem or not.

Comment: Using variables will probably help in that this is effectively the same as `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` but parameter sniffing is when a plan is compiled for one parameter value then re-used for another parameter value. The OP uses literal values so probably the statistics themselves don't accurately represent how many rows will end up matching.

Comment: The OP uses literals in his example, however, he is is hitting a proc. See comments below his question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree that this is parameter sniffing.

Apart from anything else the query you have shown doesn't use parameters!

Likely your statistics need updating and you are encountering the common issue with [ascending date columns](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/03/22/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/) that the default recompilation thresholds are not sufficient when inserting new rows and then querying the recently inserted data. [Trace flags 2389 and 2390 can help.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianjo/archive/2006/04/24/582227.aspx)

I was somewhat surprised that the unsargable predicate doesn't prevent the statistics being used but from a quick test with the following query adjusting the year does impact the estimated number of rows.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE YEAR(create_date) = 2013
```

Comment: In the comments to the question, I asked if the Year was parameterised. Apparently it is. Interesting article. Let's hope the OP gets back to us.

Comment: @MarkD - Where they reply it is a "value selected from dropdown"? Doesn't mean it is parameterised. They might be using the time honoured and SQL Injection prone string concatenation! Yes they will need to clarify.

Comment: Quite right. "@MarkD the thing is i keep running the same stored procedure for 2013 and it wont speed up. If it was a problem of sniffing wouldnt that increase the speed? – drakoumelitos 4 hours ago" means its a proc. Well, thats what I interpreted.

Comment: I don't mean to be dismissive of your suspect. I think its a more likely candidate than mine. Just don't think we can rule it out if the OP has only been firing the logic through a proc.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. First of all this is not an issue with only the query that has been exampled. But yes they are parameterized. But when i was testing them in SQL Studio i was testing the query without parameteres and in both cases the speed was slow.

Comment: i am reading the articles and i dont understand why this would be the case only with 2013 and not with 2012. The database contains data from 2009 and they are 3.1 million records inside equally distributed per month (more or less) prior to 2013 the latest records would be the ones of 2012 why should it happen now? @MartinSmith

Comment: @drakoumelitos - Quite likely the last time the statistics were updated there were a fair few rows for 2009,2010,2011,2012 but few if any 2013 records present. For a table with 3.1 million rows you could add more than 600,000 rows before the statistics will automatically be updated again. You can try `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('dbo.PrintJobsWithUserDetail' , 'PrintDate')` to see the statistics then compare the number of 2013 records shown there with the number in your actual data.